# how to display <img> in a combo instead of the tag

Tags: php

When I specify `$symbol='<img src=""></img>'`, `$symbol` is being displayed correctly everywhere in the page except in a combo box which actually displays it as a tag `"<img src=""></img>"`  itself and not the image. Pls suggest a solutions,

Comment: You can use CSS to add `background-image` on your `<option>` elements.
And use JS in order to change `<select>` background when selected option change.

Comment: Can you post the code around the combo box?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean `<select>` element when you say "combo box" (a combo box is a combination of a free text input and a drop down menu, a `<select>` element will not generate one):

The `<option>` element cannot contain markup. You cannot include images there. You should have discovered this when [performing basic automatic QA](http://validator.w3.org/) on your markup.

If you want a drop down menu that includes images, you need to build it with JavaScript and other elements.